# Removing millions of files - oneliner

Tags: perl, file, unix, rm

I want to remove millions of files in a directory and pages mentioned that the following Perl code is the fastest:

```
perl -e 'chdir "BADnew" or die; opendir D, "."; while ($n = readdir D) { unlink $n }`
```

However, is it also possible to do this on only files containing the word 'sorted'? Does anyone know how to rewrite this?

Comment: What's the fascination with one-liners?  You can convert almost any script to one line by removing newlines, but it is more important that code is readable than that it is on one line.

Comment: Any reason why `rm BADnew/*sorted*` wouldn't work?

Comment: You need to replace the `unlink $n` with a call to a function that opens the file, looks for the string you're after (`sorted`), closes the file, and then calls `unlink` if the word was found.  Not very hard; have at it!

Comment: @PaulRoub: two reasons: there are millions of files, so the argument list will be too long, and because the files contain `sorted`, not the file names.

Comment: Do you mean files whose contents contain the word *sorted* or those whose names contain the word *sorted*?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `find` and `grep` combination:

```
find BADnew -type f -exec grep -q sorted {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Second `-exec` command will be executed only if return code for first one is zero.

You can do dry run:

```
find BADnew -type f -exec grep -q sorted {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: The disadvantage with this is that it will have to create millions of processes each of which executes a single `rm` of a single file, which will make it very slow.

Comment: Yes, it's true – but it heavily depends on number of files which contain keyword – new process for `rm` will be created on match. And checking each file content will kill I/O anyway.

Comment: c=0;forks_num=10;sleep_secs=3
find . -type f -exec grep -q link {} \; -exec echo {}  \; | { while read -r file ; do c=$((c+1)) ; test $c -eq "$forks_num" && sleep "$sleep_secs" && export c=0 ; ( echo "match: $file"  )& done }

Comment: Did you read op's question? Did you try running this on a folder containing **millions** of files? It does not work. `find` builds a list in memory. Running this will destroy your system by consuming all memory, triggering disk swapping.

Answer (score 1):

the core module `File::Find` will recursively traverse all the subdirectories and perform a subroutine on all files found

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find( sub { open $f,"<",$_; unlink if grep /sorted/, <$f> }, "BADnew")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find /where -type f -name \* -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lZ sorted | xargs -0 echo rm
#can search for specific ^^^ names                       ^^^^^^            ^^^^
#                                   what should contain the file            |
#                              remove the echo if satisfied with the result +
```

The above:

- the `find` searches for files with a specified name (* - any)
- the `xargs ... grep` list files what are contains the string
- the `xargs rm` - removes the files
- don't dies on "arg count too long"
- the files could have whitespaces in their names
- needs `grep` what knows the `-Z`

Also a variant:

```
find /where -type f -name \* -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lZ sorted | perl -0 -nle unlink
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear, despite specific questions, whether you require the file *name* or the file *contents* to contain `sorted`. Here are both solutions

First, `chdir` to the directory you're interested in. If you really need a one-liner for whatever reason then it is pointless to put the `chdir` inside the program.

```
cd BADnew
```

Then you can either unlink all nodes that are files and whose name contains `sorted`

```
perl -e'opendir $dh, "."; while(readdir $dh){-f and /sorted/ and unlink}'
```

or you can open each file and read it to see if its contents contain `sorted`. I hope it's clear that this method will be far slower, not least because you have to read the entire file to establish a negative. Note that this solution relies on the

```
perl -e'opendir $dh, "."; while(readdir $dh){-f or next; @ARGV=$f=$_; /sorted/ and unlink($f),last while <>}'
```